# Largest value of sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, number-theory, optimization, ceiling-and-floor-functions

What is the idea of this problem?  I couldn't understand it

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated

EDIT: further details inside this post

[Find $\max_{i \in \mathbb{N}} a_i$ where $a_i = \left\lfloor \frac{10^{i+1}}{7}\right\rfloor-100\left\lfloor\frac{10^{i-1}}{7}\right\rfloor$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2092794/find-max-i-in-mathbbn-a-i-where-a-i-left-lfloor-frac10i17/2092900#2092900)

Comment: Please do [not use pictures for critical portions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189)
of your post. Pictures may not be legible,
cannot be searched and are not view-able to some,
such as those who use screen readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula means "what is the largest digit in decimal expansion of $\dfrac 1{13}$" ?

Since $\dfrac 1{13}=0.\overline{076923}\cdots$ then this digit is $9$.

Multiply by $10^i$ shifts the sequence to the left for instance by $1000$ we get $76.923\overline{076923}\cdots$

The entire part is $76$. The other term is shifted one less place but multiplied by $10$ so it is $70$. The difference is $6$ which is the digit at this $3^{rd}$ place in the expansion.

You can write $\displaystyle \dfrac 1{13}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} d_k10^{-k}$ apply the formula above and realize you'll find $d_i$ as an answer.

I did it once in this post :
[Find $\max_{i \in \mathbb{N}} a_i$ where $a_i = \left\lfloor \frac{10^{i+1}}{7}\right\rfloor-100\left\lfloor\frac{10^{i-1}}{7}\right\rfloor$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2092794/find-max-i-in-mathbbn-a-i-where-a-i-left-lfloor-frac10i17/2092900#2092900)

This is a bit tedious to write, please refer to that post for more details.

Answer (score 2):

The period is $$0,7,6,9,2,3,$$ which gives that $9$ is a maximum.

Answer (score 2):

The correct choice is $(D)$

The maximum value of $9$ occurs at $i=10$

that is $a_{10} =9$ is the largest.